# Separate the 'Sort by' and 'view' concepts for questions on the android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, list-questions

It seems I can not choose the sorting criteria for the questions on the android app. Maybe I am missing something, but the questions are always sorted by vote(I am talking about `unanswered questions, my tags` view here). I would like to be able to sort questions by `newest` to check if something interesting has come up.

EDIT: Actually after taking a closer view there are other views that do sort questions by post time newest to oldest. The problem is that the `view` concept is not separated from the `sort by` criteria. I would like to be able to sort `unanswered my tags`, `all questions`, `my tags`, `unanswered` by `newest`, `votes` or `activity`. I believe mixing the concepts of view and sort criteria will lead to an combination  explosion of possibilities.