# Long question title getting cut on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, title

I just posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224617/177413) using the Android app and the title turned out to be a bit lengthy. As a result, part of it is not visible on the Android app:

[image: title getting cut]

The full title is "*Separate the 'Sort by' and 'view' concepts for questions on the android app*"

What is more interesting: when I edited the question and saved it with no change, I could see "*android*" too, but "*app*" was still not visible. Second attempt to do an empty edit removed "*android*" again.

I am using the app on Nexus 5 with latest KitKat.

Comment: I have the same issue. I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2. The application version is 1.0.43.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app 1.0.82 (beta). Probably have been fixed since 1.0.50 (Q&A page renewal: removing Q&A tabs and integrate them into single thread)